# cartridge xml [IMSCC] how to included the H5P file in moodle?

Tags: moodle, cartridge, h5p

I have issue while creating cartridge XML package for moodle, It doesn't support H5P format. When i import the package into moodle, it shows h5p not found in package.

Answer (score 0):

IMS Common Cartridge 1.1 does not support h5p.

It supports only these content types:

- URL
- Folder
- LTI
- Discussion topic
- Assessment
- Static HTML

See the official standard

[IMS Common Cartridge® v1.1 Implementation](https://www.imsglobal.org/cc/ccv1p1/imscc_profilev1p1-Implementation.html)